# The EditText field is recognized as null even when I enter some data into the fields, hence the program is not proceeding further

Tags: java, android

According to the logcat the EditText remains null even after entering data.
I've tried Type-casting but still, the app crashes when registerUser function is run without the IF statements. I've also checked the ID's of both the EditText fields, they are alright.

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText emailText;
    private EditText passwordText;
    private Button registerButton;
    private TextView testView;
    private FirebaseAuth userAuth;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        emailText = findViewById(R.id.etext);
        passwordText = findViewById(R.id.ptext);
        registerButton = findViewById(R.id.rgsbutton);
        userAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        email = emailText.getText().toString().trim();
        password = passwordText.getText().toString().trim();

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkInfo();
            }
        });
    }

    public void checkInfo() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Email is required!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password is required!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            registerUser();
        }
    }

    private void registerUser() {
        userAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new
                        OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                            "User registered succesfully!",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                           task.getException().getMessage(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
    }
}
```

I expected email and password to be some string but the actual output is null. When I try run the code with IF statements on, after the button is clicked I get a toast "Email is required" even when the email is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your EditText is not null, but actually the String variables email and password contains empty values **(Not NULL Values)**. There is a difference in null and empty. 
What happening in your case is when you are launching the application, the `onCreate()` is called.

Inside `onCreate()` you are initializing your views. This is correct. But just after initializing your EditTexts (at this moment EditText do not contains any values) you are reading the values. And thus you are having Empty values in  your String variables.

And when the button is clicked you are calling the function `checkInfo()` inside this function you are checking if your email and password are empty or not. And the point is your email and password are always empty because you are not taking input values on button click.

So the simple solution is get the input when the button is clicked. So move the input code inside your function check info.

```
public void checkInfo() {
    email = emailText.getText().toString().trim();
    password = passwordText.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email is required!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password is required!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        registerUser();
    }
}
```

Now you will have no problem proceeding further. I hope you explained in a clear way. If you are still having some problem understanding what your mistake was, let me know.

Thank You :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining it so nicely :)  ...Yes, I acknowledged my mistake, but the now the problem is, User is not getting registered(i.e Getting the toast message "Error! Please try again!"...What must be the problem?

Comment: try `task.getException().getMessage()` instead of hardcoded string inside your else block. It will display the actual error that is happening. Also make sure you have enabled the email authentication in firebase console.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you. And additionally for more information you can check a complete course about Firebase Auth here: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hhUCFBSnVTECda_MdTp3GnQ

Comment: I implemented task.getException().getMessage().....It solved my problem the password was supposed to be of minimum 6 characters. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Add these two lines inside button click listner

```
email = emailText.getText().toString().trim();
    password = passwordText.getText().toString().trim();
```

that means after your code modification...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText emailText;
private EditText passwordText;
private Button registerButton;
private TextView testView;
private FirebaseAuth userAuth;
private String email;
private String password;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    emailText =  findViewById(R.id.etext);
    passwordText =  findViewById(R.id.ptext);
    registerButton =  findViewById(R.id.rgsbutton);
    userAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    email = emailText.getText().toString().trim();
    password = passwordText.getText().toString().trim();

           checkInfo();
        }
    });
}
public void  checkInfo(){
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Email is required!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Password is required!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        registerUser();
    }
}
private void registerUser(){
    userAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new 
OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "User registered succesfully!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Error!Please try again!", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            email = emailText.getText().toString().trim(); //check after the click
            password = passwordText.getText().toString().trim(); //check after the click
            checkInfo();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `email = emailText.getText().toString().trim(); password = passwordText.getText().toString().trim();` from onCreate() to checkInfo().

Answer (score 0):

You are getting value from `EditText` fields in OnCreate method. So it means it will only execute once but not by clicking on the button. So the solution is to get value from `EditText` inside the `click listener`, so every time fresh value should be retrieved from the `EditText` by clicking on button, instead of getting just only at start when its empty and returning `null`.

```
registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            email = emailText.getText().toString().trim();        //
            password = passwordText.getText().toString().trim();  //these 2 lines are moved here

            checkInfo();
        }
    });
```